# How are U.S retirement accounts (401k, IRA) withdrawals taxed in Colombia if I become a resident for tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement, colombia

I'm currently a U.S resident (not citizen) and I have money invested in a 401k account. I'm planning to move to Colombia at some point in the future. How are 401k withdrawals taxed there? I cannot find any info online regarding tax treatment of foreign retirement accounts in Colombia.